# Wagtail > add gallery_images to multiple apps (page model instances)

Tags: image, wagtail

I followed the tutorial https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.6.2/getting_started/tutorial.html 
and added to my blog app `class BlogPageGalleryImage(Orderable):` then `def main_image(self):` to the `class BlogPage(Page):` which worked. 
But I have two more apps (**projects** and **events**) with page instances similar to **blog** and cannot add galleries to them the same way. 
Should I implement the gallery into the Page class itself?

I have 4 apps (blog, about, events, projects) and in the model definitions *IndexPage, *Page, *PageGalleryImages respectively.

For example in the events app's models.py I defined

```
class EventPageGalleryImages(Orderable): 
    page = ParentalKey(EventPage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='gallery_images') 
    image = models.ForeignKey( 'wagtailimages.Image', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+' ) 
    caption = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250) 
    panels = [ ImageChooserPanel('image'), FieldPanel('caption'), ]
```

but I get an error by makemigrations:

```
(ma_env) ➜  ma_app git:(0.15) ✗ ./manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/DEV/ma_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/DEV/ma_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/DEV/ma_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/DEV/ma_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/DEV/ma_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/DEV/ma_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/DEV/ma_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/DEV/ma_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/DEV/ma_app/events/models.py", line 24, in <module>
    class EventPage(Page):
  File "/home/DEV/ma_app/events/models.py", line 53, in EventPage
    class EventPageGalleryImages(Orderable):
  File "/home/DEV/ma_app/events/models.py", line 54, in EventPageGalleryImages
    page = ParentalKey(EventPage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='gallery_images')
NameError: name 'EventPage' is not defined
```

Comment: "cannot add galleries to them the same way" - why not? What happens when you try?

Comment: Hi gasman, and thanks for Wagtail!!! 

I have 4 apps (blog, about, events, projects) and in the model definitions *IndexPage, *Page, *PageGalleryImages respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the last few lines of the stack trace, it looks like you've defined `EventPageGalleryImages` inside the definition of `EventPage`:

```
class EventPage(Page):
    # ...

    class EventPageGalleryImages(Orderable):
        page = ParentalKey(EventPage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='gallery_images') 
        # ...
```

This is failing because you refer to `EventPage` in the `ParentalKey` definition, but the definition of `EventPage` hasn't been completed yet. Removing the indent from the second class definition should fix it.

Comment: Ooo, such a dumb mistake in python .:/ 
Thank you! (I have answered this already but I don't see the post here.)